# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' in TableWidgets

Tags: python, nonetype

I was trying to work with TableWidgets on Python and I ran into an issue.

I wanted to check whether the table is filled or not (with `str` of course).

```
def add_table (self):
    self.kala = self.comboBox.currentText()
    self.code_kala = self.comboBox.currentIndex()
    self.vahed = self.comboBox_2.currentText()
    list_e = []
    for i in list(range(10)):
        #self.tab = self.tableWidget.item(i,0)
        if self.tableWidget.item(i,0).text() != '':
        #if self.tab.text() !='':
            list_e.append(i)
        else:
            pass
    self.ROW = len(list_e)
    self.tableWidget.setItem(self.ROW,0,QTableWidgetItem(self.kala))
    self.tableWidget.setItem(self.ROW,1,QTableWidgetItem(str(self.code_kala)))
    self.tableWidget.setItem(self.ROW,2,QTableWidgetItem(str(self.vahed)))
```

and I don't know why I keep getting this error:

`NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Also, I know this code doesn't have any problem (I got good results with the same code in another project) but as `cmd` said:

```
File "D:\**\***\*****\*******\*\*************.py", line 1755, in add_table
    if self.tableWidget.item(i,0).text() != '':
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Comment: `NoneType` Means the variable has nothing in it. You could use a debugger to check why the variable is empty.

Comment: You could print the object just before the conditional statement and that should give you a clue which item is missing. Or you could [Catch the error](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) and inspect/print relevant data in the except suite. One of your table items is empty: if you expect to have empty *cells(?)* catch the error and `pass` in the except suite.

Comment: As an aside: you can iterate over a range object without making a list from it : `for i in list(range(10)): -->> for i in range(10):`.  And I was looking through some SO Q&A's like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11974735/2823755) - seems that `Qtables`(?) have a `rowCount()` method so the for statement becomes - `for i in self.tableWidget.rowCount()`.

Comment: @wwii ty man i found my problem with Your solution i used print function and i got None after 10 times ' ' so i changed the range(10) to range(9) and solved it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the table widget might contain 'None' values, so you have to expect them to pop up. Instead of doing this:

```
    if self.tableWidget.item(i,0).text() != '':
```

do that:

```
    thing = self.tableWidget.item(i,0)
    if thing is not None and thing.text() != '':
        # do stuff with thing
```

Comment: You Are amazing man 
i can stop  this bug with your code ( however i found the problem) but i think your solution is Temporary because its not solving the problem it just dealing with it(Get off with it) and the actuall problem was range(10) i had to change it to 9 its funny how hard programming is

Comment: I am glad it was useful to you. Programming is not so much achieving end results as it is understanding all the building blocks and the tools to get you there. From now on, you will be able to recognize the pattern `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`